# For cameras that use SD card for storage

Tags: sata, storage, sd-card

I need a cheap Network Video Recorder. Can I simply connect the contacts for an SD card slot on the camera to the contacts in the slot of this adapter (http://img.dxcdn.com/productimages/sku_194037_1.jpg) and have a camera that can interface through SATA of any computer? I can simply fashion a male-male connector between the 2 of them.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

This adapter lets you use SD card as a SATA drive, not the other way around.

Comment: I was afraid of that. They're both serial with very different standards. Just had to check.

Comment: How about using a SD to IDE adapter https://www.amazon.ca/44-Pin-Male-IDE-Card-Adapter/dp/B003MN1H9U (I've heard that only the early SD uses IDE interface, but I'm assuming this one works perfectly), then plugging this in to a typical IDE to SATA http://www.lightinthebox.com/new-3-5-ide-hdd-to-sata-100-133-serial-ata-converter-adapter-cable-0-2m_p761507.html

Comment: Same - it's SD to IDE, not IDE to SD. I've never heard about SD cards using IDE interface, it's against the spec. CF cards did use IDE, though, but that doesn't solve your problem.